# How to override search in Magento?

Tags: search, magento, customization

My user should be able to use the search box to search by some attribute (numeric) it works.

But I'd like to my customer to be able to search using separator.

Example:

search by : 12345678 = works great

search by : 12-34-56-78 = doesn't work

Which will the best way to override magento search to parse/rewrite/modify this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: please verify your search settings and how they are currently set up in system > configuration > catalog > catalog search

Comment: I changed FULLTEXT to LIKE, and it looks like it accepts now - or other special chars and incomplete reference to be found. Do you now where can I find more information about how it works? By the way please consider make it an answer I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want to override the default search (OOP override, that is) Refer to my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311045/how-to-override-default-search-in-magento).

Otherwise @Anton's answer may be enough for you to use the default search which is always preferable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you link, but I took a look at the code, but I'm not able to start, I don't really know how the magento search works, and the coode is full of prepareResult, rebuildIndex which I don't understand, I know how to do basic search, but it is something to complex for me to understand at the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Admin -> Catalog -> Search Terms -> Add New Search term.

Define variants of the searches you want to be redirected else where or found.